# Roblox: Parts not being cloned

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a script that summons cars randomly. I haven't seen a car being summoned or any errors in the console.

I tried this code which SHOULD choose one of the random cars and clone them:

```lua
function MakeCar(towardPlayers: boolean)
    local Car:MeshPart = script[tostring(math.random(1,45))]:Clone()
    Car.Anchored = false
    if towardPlayers then
        Car.Position = Vector3.new(-119.75, 5, -32)
        Car.Orientation = Vector3.new(0, -90, 0)
        while Car do
            Car.Position += Vector3.new(2, 0, 0)
            wait(0.01)
        end
    else
        Car.Position = Vector3.new(119.75, 5, -48.25 / 100))
        Car.Orientation = Vector3.new(0, 90, 0)
        while Car do
            Car.Position -= Vector3.new(2, 0, 0)
            wait(0.01)
        end
    end
end
while true do
    MakeCar(true)
    wait(math.random(100, 10000) / 100)
end
while true do
    MakeCar(false)
    wait(math.random(100, 10000) / 100)
end
```

I was expecting a random car to show up and drive on the road, but I get nothing. Not even an output in the console. So I have no idea what's going on in the script.

What might be important:

- I double checked the `Position` and made sure it would land on the road
- It is a `Script`, not a `LocalScript`

Comment: Is the script a child of workspace else you might have to change Car.Parent

Comment: You probably need to set the car's Parent to `workspace` or where you want to be.

Comment: Yes, Script is a child of Workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the car's Parent to the `workspace` so that the car exists in the game.

Why? Only `Parts`, `Models`, ... exist physically in the game when it has it's parent in the `workspace`.

```lua
Car.Parent = workspace
```